# follow a question

Tags: support, questions, list-questions

How i can follow a question without bookmarking the question web page ?

is there any specific way to follow an interest question and be mailed when some one write down another answer or some change are made ?

Answer (score 1):

You can mark it as a favorite (the star underneath the vote area next to the question). Then whenever the question is ansered or commented on, the envelope next to your username at the top of the window will turn red. You can click on that, and it will take you to your inbox where you can see what changes occurred.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the RSS feed - found at the bottom right _\| of every question page.